# How do I know if I am using AWS Certificate Manager correctly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

What is my indication that I am using AWS Certificate Manager correctly and that any remaining problems getting my site to load at https are due to a mistake I am making in my Apache configuration?

In AWS Certificate Manager, I see **"Success! Your certificate was issued successfully."**  Does that mean there are no further steps for me to complete in the AWS console, and I need only get my Apache configuration correct to finish?

Currently, when I try to visit a URL at my site with the http protocol, it loads fine, but when I visit at https, the browser tries to load the page but it never loads.

I have followed the instructions for creating an HTTPS listener, but still do not know if I am done with all necessary steps in AWS console.  How would I know?

Edit:  To clarify, I am using an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB), since the documentation indicated I need to use ELB with AWS Certificate Manager (ACM).  However, I do not know how to determine if I have configured everything correctly in AWS console that I need to in order to access the site at HTTPS.

Edit 2:  This might come close to answering my question, possibly, but I don't know how to do this: "You can use curl, telnet etc from your local machine to verify 443 port status on ELB" -- @vivekyad4v.

Answer (score 1):

ACM(AWS Certificate Manager) supports the AWS resources like ELB, Cloudfront, API Gateway etc. You can add SSL certificates to these 
resources via AWS console.

Currently, it doesn't support EC2. You cannot use ACM with EC2 instances, you will need a Load Balancer in front of it. Once you have a load balancer, SSL termination happens on the load balancer & not on the EC2 instance.

Once it is setup, you can change your apache server config to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS.

Add certificate to ELB - "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-update-ssl-cert.html"

Update apache config - "https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/"

> No EC2 support - "https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/"

Comment: I have a load balancer in front of it.  I am using ELB.  How do I know when I am done with the AWS configuration and have done it properly, and any remaining problems are in my Apache configuration?  Thank you!

Comment: Have you added the SSL certificate to your ELB? Once added you just need a redirect on Apache server, no other config changes.

Comment: Yes, I added the certificate to my ELB.  Will I see some indication in AWS console that I am done?  Is there some simple test I can do on the server to confirm that I have configured things correctly in AWS console?  Thanks again.

Comment: You can use `curl`, `telnet` etc from your local machine to verify `443 port` status on ELB. However, on the console there is nothing which tells you that "Yes, your website is HTTPS now".

Comment: Thanks again, and this comes close to answering the question:  "You can use curl, telnet etc from your local machine to verify 443 port status on ELB."   I will try googling that to see if I can figure out how to do that.  Initially, I don't know how.  It sounds like I may have things configured correctly in AWS, but I don't know.  As I work on correcting my Apache config, I won't know if I'm making matters better or worse, since I can't confirm that I have done things correctly in AWS console.

Comment: In my Target Groups, I see that my "Registered Targets" are "unhealthy".  I don't know what that means, but if I hover over the info icons I see that my 443 times out and my 80 returns a 401 error.  Alas, I don't know what to do with that information.

Comment: You need to add a HTTP status code for healthcheck in target groups w.r.t your EC2 instances. You can define a range i.e 200-499. If EC2 instances HTTP response code lies in that range, load balancer will mark it as healthy. Ref - "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html"

Comment: Thanks.  With that change, the check on port 80 is health and 443 is unhealthy.  I suppose I was seeing 401 code for port 80 because I have apache authentication in front of the site. So that would explain the 401, and I now understand the health checks -- I guess they are not relevant to the issue.  Good to know though.